# He is a single-eater friend

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Imagine you have a friend. He doesn't share good stuff with his other friends. For example, he gets a fine bottle of booze, but he drinks it without his friends.
Or he has pizza and he doesn't share.

In my language, we have a term for such friend which literally translates to "single-eater".

Is there a specific term in English for such a friend?

I already know a term like "fair-weather" friend but it doesn't work here.

This term (single-eater) is used jokingly among friends in my language most of the time.

Comment: Sounds like a *Loner*.

Comment: Joey doesn't share food!

Comment: No. I don't mean a loner. This is something you would say to your close friends. When you are being critical of the fact that they have something good and they are unwilling to share it with their close friends.

Comment: You might try to use the description of "single-serving friend" from *Fight Club*. Possibly it could be adapted.

Comment: Doesn't that mean a temporary friend? https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=single%20serving%20friend  In my language, you would say "single-eater" to your closest friends. Ones you have been friends with for a long time and you will probably continue to be. It's a joke meant to encourage your friends to share with you. Example: Come on man! Don't be a single-eater. Share that nice bottle of wine you got with us.

Comment: I can't think of a standard phrase that covers this habitual, but we sometimes use the template *an X-hog* to describe a person who is not sharing X.  As in, "don't be a pizza-hog, give me a slice."

Comment: He is selfish. . .